# WPF ListView inside Grouped TreeView not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

In a WPF Project I have a set of `record` objects with the properties `School`, `Subject`, `FirstName` and `LastName`. The records are grouped by `School` and `Subject` using `CollectionViewSource` in XAML and this is used by a `TreeView` to show the grouped items. The groupings work fine.

The problem is I would like to show the `FirstName` and `LastName` of the records under the `Subject` in a `ListView` using a `GridView` as its View with `FirstName` and `LastName` as columns, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Here is an image of the current display:

[image]

Here's some sample code to show what I mean.

```
public class Record
{
    public string School { get; set; }
    public string  Subject { get; set; }
    public  string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        var records = new Record[]
        {
            new Record() { School = "School A", Subject = "Maths" , FirstName = "Fred" , LastName = "Blogs"},
            new Record() { School = "School A", Subject = "English" , FirstName = "Alice" , LastName = "Lane"},
            new Record() { School = "School B", Subject = "Geography" , FirstName = "John" , LastName = "Smith"},
            new Record() { School = "School B", Subject = "Geography" , FirstName = "Burt" , LastName = "Lancaster"},
            new Record() { School = "School C", Subject = "Chemistry" , FirstName = "Dee" , LastName = "Kaye"}

        };

        this.DataContext = records;
    }
}
```

XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewInTreeView.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewInTreeView"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="listings"                   
                  Source="{Binding .}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="School" />
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Subject" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>

    <TreeView Grid.Row="4" DataContext="{StaticResource listings}"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" >

        <TreeView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander Margin="0,0,0,0" IsExpanded="True" BorderBrush="#FFA4B97F" 
                                    BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <DockPanel>
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text=" : "/>
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                                                <TextBlock Text=" items(s)"/>
                                            </DockPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <Expander.Content>
                                            <ItemsPresenter Margin="20,0,0,0" />
                                        </Expander.Content>
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </TreeView.GroupStyle>

        <TreeView.Resources>

            <!-- NEED HELP HERE I THINK ?-->
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 `GroupStyle`s, one for the `School` group and another one for the `Subject` group:

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="4" DataContext="{StaticResource listings}"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
    <TreeView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Expander Margin="0,0,0,0" IsExpanded="True" BorderBrush="#FFA4B97F" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <DockPanel>
                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text=" : "/>
                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text=" items(s)"/>
                                        </DockPanel>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <Expander.Content>
                                        <ItemsPresenter Margin="20,0,0,0" />
                                    </Expander.Content>
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Expander Margin="0,0,0,0" IsExpanded="True" BorderBrush="#FFA4B97F"  BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                                    <Expander.Header>
                                        <DockPanel>
                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text=" : "/>
                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text=" items(s)"/>
                                        </DockPanel>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <Expander.Content>
                                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                                            <ListView.View>
                                                <GridView>
                                                    <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"/>
                                                </GridView>
                                            </ListView.View>
                                        </ListView>
                                    </Expander.Content>
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </TreeView.GroupStyle>
</TreeView>
```

You probably also want to move the common property settings for the `Expander` and `GroupItem` to two styles that are used by both `GroupStyle`s:

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="4" DataContext="{StaticResource listings}"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Expander">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFA4B97F" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1" />
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding}" />
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DockPanel>
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text=" : "/>
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text=" items(s)"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Expander>
                                    <Expander.Content>
                                        <ItemsPresenter Margin="20,0,0,0" />
                                    </Expander.Content>
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Expander>
                                    <Expander.Content>
                                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                                            <ListView.View>
                                                <GridView>
                                                    <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"/>
                                                </GridView>
                                            </ListView.View>
                                        </ListView>
                                    </Expander.Content>
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </TreeView.GroupStyle>
</TreeView>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @mm8 , it works great! Thanks!. Not sure why however. Don't understand how second `Style` is being picked up correctly as they both target nothing more specific than `GroupItem` ?